# How can I combine these two filters in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

So Im trying to overlay a video on top of an image and then add text over the image in ffmpeg I found that Im able to do all these separately but when combining it gives me the error of

`Cannot find a matching stream for unlabeled input pad 0 on filter Parsed_drawtext_2`

The line of code:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i overlay.png -re
-i overlay.mp4 
-filter_complex "[1]scale=1660:934[inner];[0][inner]overlay=0:0:shortest=1[out];
drawtext=fontsize=40:fontfile=FreeSerif.ttf:textfile=text.txt:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2:reload=1"
-map "[out]" -map 1:a -c:a copy -y -s 1280x800 output.mp4
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost got it. Only needs some re-arranging:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i overlay.png
-i overlay.mp4 
-filter_complex "[1]scale=1660:934[inner];[0][inner]overlay=0:0:shortest=1,scale=1280:800,drawtext=fontsize=40:fontfile=FreeSerif.ttf:textfile=text.txt:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2:reload=1[out]"
-map "[out]" -map 1:a -c:a copy output.mp4
```

See [FFmpeg filtering intro](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Filtering-Introduction) for a quick explanation of the syntax.